# CouchDB view is extremely slow

Tags: performance, couchdb

I have a CouchDB (v0.10.0) database that is 8.2 GB in size and contains 3890000 documents.

Now, I have the following as the Map of the view

```
function(doc) {emit([doc.Status], doc);
```

And it takes **forever** to load (4 hours and still no result).

Here's some extra information that might help describing the situation:

1. The view is not a temp view. The
   view is defined before the 3890000
   documents are inserted.
2. There isn't anything on the server. It is a ubuntu box with nothing but the defaults installed.
3. I see that my CPU is moving and working hard (sometimes shoots to 100%). The memory is moving as well but not increasing.

So my question is:

1. What is actually happening in the background?
2. Is this a "one time" thing where I have to wait once and it will somehow works later?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Views are only updated the next time they are read. Upon reading, it processes all the documents that have been updated (created, updated, deleted) since the last time the view was read.

So even if you're view was defined before inserting the 3890000 documents, it will be processing the 3890000 documents for the view.

From http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views

> Note that by default views are not created and updated when a document is saved, but rather, when they are accessed. As a result, the first access might take some time depending on the size of your data while CouchDB creates the view. If preferable the views can also be updated when a document is saved using an external script that calls the views when updates have been made. An example can be found here: [RegeneratingViewsOnUpdate](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/RegeneratingViewsOnUpdate)

Also just came across this tip, which might be useful if you're running on Ubuntu:

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1299848121/couchdb-and-ubuntu-configuration-trick-for

Comment: Perfect! So I guess it is building the index at that time. And even if I reboot it will not do this (since update is done). Thanks Evan!

Answer (score 17):

Don't emit the whole doc.  It's unnecessary.  You can instead run your query with `include_docs=true`, which will let you access the document via each row's doc attribute.

When you emit the whole doc you make the index as large or larger than your entire database. :)

Comment: Mikeal is right, although I'll add in another thread JasonSmith mentioned that if you emit the doc into an index, the index will be much bigger but retrieval will be faster. But as Mikeal points out this will make your indices basically end up being copies of your data set, so if you are working with BIG data, don't emit it :)

Comment: So how would the emit look like then? emit(doc.id)?